# ¿Se puede usar "hablar" en un texto?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

Me preguntaba si se puede escribir:

"Tu hablas de..."

"Estoy hablando con..."

Cuando se está comunicando por mensajería como WhatsApp o Instagram.

Creo que está aceptado el "decir" pero no estoy seguro del "hablar" dado que se usa verbalmente.

Comment: Y porque no? En tu opinión? Decir no es hablar. Se habla por WhatsApp y se dice X.

Answer (score 3):

Del DLE, *hablar*:

> 3. intr. Dicho de una persona: Comunicarse con otra u otras por medio de palabras.

> 9. intr. Tratar de algo **por escrito**

*Decir* es un verbo transitivo y no puede usarse en vez de *hablar*, un verbo intransitivo.

❌*Estoy diciendo con él* --- ✅*Estoy hablando con él*

❌*Le hablé algo* --- ✅*Le dije algo*

Answer (score 1):

Claro que se puede usar; lo oigo frecuentemente. Como por ejemplo:

1. Te estoy hablando al Whatsapp.
2. Estoy hablando con Ana por Instagram.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible su uso, según la Real Academia Española, una de las definiciones de **hablar** es *tratar de algo por escrito*.

Comment: ienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.